# SSO implementation in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I wanted to know how can I implement the SSO authentication between multiple applications using the **SAML** in ASP.NET Core?

Is this a safe and secure way to do it?

If you know the information, better free method or how to implement it, write it down.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think free method exists. Unless you want to implement solution from scratch by yourself, which seems to be a lot of work to do.

So, if it's an option you could use some commercial solutions. I have experience working with [ComponentSpace.Saml2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ComponentSpace.Saml2/). Configuration is pretty straightforward - you need to fill and store a bunch of configuration items such as identity providers' params, certificates data, login and logout endpoints. Then controller needs to be built, containing methods for initiating saml request and processing response from identity provider. That's just infratructure level - of course you'll need to implement authentication service to manage SAML response and to decide how it integrates into your app's architecture.

Well, as you can see, the answer is general, so is the question.

Hope this helps. At least to choose right path to go.